# Replacing my exec() code bit

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a script that allows me to type something into the command line, and have it show the corresponding list. For example, if I run it, and print

Here is the essential bits:

```
list_of_strings = ['mexico', 'america', 'canada']
list_of_lists = [ [0,0,0,3], [4,9,3,6], [5,6,7] ]


for name in range(len(list_of_strings)):
        exec(list_of_strings[name] + ' = list_of_lists[name]')
```

running this, and typing "america' (no quotes), returns [4,9,3,6].

My problem is when I want to convert this bit into a function, like

```
def my_zip(list_of_strings, list_of_lists):
    for name in range(len(list_of_strings)):
        return exec(list_of_strings[name] + ' = list_of_lists[name]')

my_zip(list_of_strings, list_of_lists)
```

It no longer works. 'america' (no quotes) is not recognized as a variable.

I feel like I should be using a dictionary, but any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

3 major issues:

1. `exec` doesn't return anything.
2. You have `return` inside the `for` loop. It will only run for one iteration. Because of that and the fact that `exec` returns nothing, it will immediately return `None` after one iteration.
3. You are using `exec` to begin with. You should edit your question to include what you are really trying to do. There is probably a better and more secure way of doing so.